# why is localstorage on phonegap Cordova working on iOS10 but not iOS 9?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, local-storage

Working on a cordova application.
I’ve updated everything for iOS 10. local storage works great on iOS 10 but is not working at all on iOS 9. Why ?

A simple sample of my code:

```
localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(eventsList), 1);
var dataCached = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "events" ) );
```

Is there anything we should pay attention with localstorage on different versions of iOS ? It used to work just fine before I did a `cordova platform update ios` and updated cordova.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to low memory localStorage randomly cleared out after iOS 8 so probably that thing was removed in iOS 10, didn't tested yet

for more info see this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-localstorage-persistence/20004/11

Comment: My issue is that it doesn’t even store it. Some action required accessing data stored in localstorage for 10 secs and even that doesn’t work. The user doesn’t leave the app.